# Field Extensions of Countable Sets

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

I was wondering, for a field F that is a countable set, and E/F algebraic, is field E necessarily countable as well?

I know algebraic field extension implies every element of E is a root of a polynomial in F[x]. However, I'm not sure how to show if E is countable or not.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So every element of $E$ is in the set of the roots of polynomials over $F$. What is the cardinality of this set? Hint: a countable union of countable sets is still countable.

Comment: F is countable, so its polynomial ring is also countable, since as you said, a countable union of countable sets is countable. Does this mean the roots of these polynomials are also countable?

Comment: Yes, since each polynomial has a finite number of roots.

Comment: I see! Thanks. :)